# How to handle Pending intent from notification

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, kotlin, android-notifications

If I have an application with have

```
A -> B -> C -> D
```

in stack. How could I open an activity from Notification and make stack become

```
A -> B -> C -> D -> E
```

And if application is terminated, how could I open application from notification like open E activity from notification but prevent it from launch when open application again [For example, I open E activity then I backpress to exit an application then when I open application again I want it to open A activity(Root Activity) instead of E activity.]

```
// When Open Application if app is terminated.

val intent = Intent(activity!!, SampleActivity::class.java)
val pendingIntent= PendingIntent.getActivity(activity!!, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)

        with(NotificationManagerCompat.from(activity!!)) {

            notify(
                java.lang.System.currentTimeMillis().toInt(), notiBuilder
                    .setContentTitle("Title")
                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                    .setContentText("body")
                    .setNumber(1)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_icon_background)
                    .setBadgeIconType(NotificationCompat.BADGE_ICON_SMALL)
                    .build())

        }


// When Open Application if app is not terminated.

val intent = Intent(activity!!, HomeActivity::class.java)
intent.putExtra("FurtherActivity", 1)    
intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK   

val pendingIntent= PendingIntent.getActivity(activity!!, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)

        with(NotificationManagerCompat.from(activity!!)) {

            notify(
                java.lang.System.currentTimeMillis().toInt(), notiBuilder
                    .setContentTitle("Title")
                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                    .setContentText("body")
                    .setNumber(1)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_icon_background)
                    .setBadgeIconType(NotificationCompat.BADGE_ICON_SMALL)
                    .build())

        }

// HomeActivity

override fun onCreate() {
    ......
    ......
    ......
    if(intent.getIntExtra("FurtherActivity", 0) == 1) {
        SampleActivity.start(this@HomeActivity)
        viewpager.currentItem = 0
        tab_layout.getTabAt(0)!!.select()
    }
    ......
    ......
}

override fun onNewIntent(newIntent: Intent?) {
    super.onNewIntent(Intent())
    if(intent.getIntExtra("FurtherActivity", 0) == 1) {
        SampleActivity.start(this@HomeActivity)
        viewpager.currentItem = 0
        tab_layout.getTabAt(0)!!.select()
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want to increase the chances of your question being answered I suggest you include a piece of example code that demonstrates your issue so that person answering can suggest correctiobs instead of writing everything from scratch.

Comment: @IcedLance Thanks to remind me, I forgot to add my code

Answer (score 0):

you can create an activity which handle intent result and will pass that result to specific activities based on requirements
then just pass HandleIntent activity to notification intent with ActivityName as parameters to open specific activity.